# Unit tests stopped working on migration from vs2008 to vs2012

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

After migrating a solution which includes unittests from vs2008 to vs2012, all unittests suddenly stopped working.

When running these unittests (both through the Test Explorer in Visual Studio, aswell as testing through ReSharper 7.1), they end up being failed tests with this error being shown for each test:

**"QTAgent32.exe has stopped working"**

When I remove the use of the testsettingsfile(vs2008), all tests run. I added its content for reference. Also, when adding a new testsettingsfile originated from vs2012, the tests do not run either.

What is the problem here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestSettings name="Local Test Run" id="03ca7a8e-b906-4d31-9608-087e8dfe7c60" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Description>This is a default test run configuration for a local test run.</Description>
  <Execution>
    <TestTypeSpecific>
      <WebTestRunConfiguration testTypeId="4e7599fa-5ecb-43e9-a887-cd63cf72d207">
        <Browser name="Internet Explorer 7.0">
          <Headers>
            <Header name="User-Agent" value="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)" />
            <Header name="Accept" value="*/*" />
            <Header name="Accept-Language" value="{{$IEAcceptLanguage}}" />
            <Header name="Accept-Encoding" value="GZIP" />
          </Headers>
        </Browser>
      </WebTestRunConfiguration>
      <UnitTestRunConfig testTypeId="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b">
        <AssemblyResolution>
          <TestDirectory useLoadContext="true" />
        </AssemblyResolution>
      </UnitTestRunConfig>
    </TestTypeSpecific>
    <AgentRule name="LocalMachineDefaultRole">
    </AgentRule>
  </Execution>
</TestSettings>
```

Comment: Try using .runsettings instead of test settings http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx